# CPP: Class as private member in another class

Tags: c++, class, methods

For example, I create a Button class. `Button` should have its own text (with color, size, font, spacing, etc.), states and background.

Because text labels are useful even in another widgets (text labels, text edits, etc.) I put all needed in another class (call it `Label`).

Background color is useful too, so I created another class - `Color` with all needed methods - changing, comparing...

Now come back to Button class.

```
class Button {
    private:
        Color _bgColor;
        Label _text;

        /* another private members */

    public:
        /* Content of Button class */
};
```

But what if I would like to change the button background color? In this case, I need to write another two methods => `setColor` and `getColor`. In fact, I have to write all methods which are defined for `Color` class.

Another option is to define private classes as public and access them like `button.bgColor.setColor()`. But it seems weird to me to one time call `button.disable` and another time `button.color.setColor`.

Is there any other option which I don't know about? Thank you for help.

Comment: I think you've summarized your choices very well.

Comment: Good to know :) Well, there is no better solution than using classes as public methods? Using of `friend` is indicator of wrong desing.

Comment: It all depends on how much you value convenience vs. encapsulation.

Comment: As lazy man I will probably prefer the convenience. On the other hand,  I should do things "the good way" from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that when something has attributes those attributes need to be exposed somehow, and that can lead to code bloat.  However, as with all things a simple layer of abstraction can make things easier.

You can provide "helper classes" for these types of attributes and use them as mixins.  This will keep the code as small as possible while still

```
class HasLabel
{
public:
   void SetLabelText(const std::string& text);
   const std::string& GetLabelText() const;

private:
   Label label_;
};

class HasBackgroundColor
{
public:
   void SetBackgroundColor(const Color& color);
   const Color& GetBackgroundColor() const;

private:
   Color color_;
};

class Button : private HasBackgroundColor, private HasLabel
{
public:
   // Expose BkColor
   using HasBackgroundColor::SetLabelText;
   using HasBackgroundColor::GetLabelText;

   // Expose Label
   using HasLabel::SetLabelText;
   using HasLabel::GetLabelText;
};
```

You could also use public inheritance and then the `using` directives wouldn't be necessary, but whether that's acceptable (if a `Button` truly "is-a" `HasLabel`) is a matter of personal preference.

You could also use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to reduce the amount of boilerplate code for objects with similar mixins.

Comment: This looks nice. However I don't see difference between this and the answer from haansn08. Above that, this method require another two classes.

Comment: Agreed, if the only object type in question is a `Button`.  However, if there are other object types that have similar attributes (`ScrollBar`, `ListBox`), these mixins provide a way to have less code  that is boilerplate, and more code that is shared (making maintenance easier over time).

Answer (score 1):

> But what if I would like to change the button background color? In this case, I need to
>   write another two methods => setColor and getColor. In fact, I have to write all methods  which are defined for Color class.

Why would you do that?
Just define a function `SetBackgroundColor(Color &newColor)` for setting the color and `const Color& GetBackgroundColor() const` for accessing it!

Comment: In the `Button`-Class. (Is there a difference between functions and methods?)

Comment: I think method is a function used in class. class::method(), but function()

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I would like to change the button background color? In this case, I need to write another two methods => `setColor` and `getColor`. In fact, I have to write all methods which are defined for `Color` class.

Not true.  You only need to write those two methods.  Anything else just happens through the `getColor` return value.  For example, to test if two buttons have the same color, you'd write:

```
if (button1.getColor() == button2.getColor())
```

not

```
if (button1.hasSameColor(button2))
```

That is, unless you want to hide `Button`'s use of the `Color` class as an "implementation detail."  I wouldn't recommend that.  Programs dealing with color should usually treat colors as a value type, akin to plain numbers, points, vectors, etc.

Comment: This leads to long "acces" chain. For example rather using `button.setFont(button2.setFont())`, you have to use `button.getFont().setFont(button2.getFont())`. I know, bad example.

Comment: For your first line, did you mean `button.setFont(button2.getFont())`?

Comment: Your code will work. But as I said, it leads to long source code. You always have to call .getColor before working with it. Nothing more.

Comment: The second line of code in your comment doesn't make sense.  Why would `Font` have a `setFont()` method?